# get list of all child object ids after user clicks with angular6

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm displaying list of records from an API on a page. the page displays both parent and child objects.

JSON Data

```
const dataList = [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Past Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-08 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "6",
        "description": "6",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 6,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Good Menu",
    "serveDate": "2019-05-10 00:00:00",
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "7",
        "description": "7",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 7,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "9",
        "description": "9",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 9,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      },
      {
        "id": 31,
        "name": "10",
        "description": "10",
        "image": "",
        "mealType": "BREAKFAST",
        "unitPrice": 10,
        "status": "ENABLED"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

HTML VIEW

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menuList">
    <h2 (click)="getMealsIds()">Menu</h2>
    {{item.name}} - {{item.servedate}}
  <h2>Meals</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let meal of item.meals">
        <span (click)="removeMeal(meal, item.id)">{{meal.name}} - {{meal.mealType}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want to achieve is when  a particular menu is clicked, I should be able to get all the meals ids in an array

FUNCTION

```
getMealsIds(parent) {
console.log(parent.meals.id)
}
```

Any help on how to make this work as it should? With my current script when its clicked i an error undefined

Comment: In your html you iterate your loop by using a `menulist` variable but in your question i am not able to find that variable in your `TS`. second thing is that in your `getMealsIds()` function in `ts` have one parameter called parent but in your html you did't pass any parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `map` the array. if `parent` is `dataList[0]` then

```
console.log(parent.meals.map(m => m.id)); // [27, 28, 30]
```